# MATCH AGAINST SQL Query on MariaDB not working as expected

Tags: full-text-search, mariadb

I am working on a project where I am using MySQL MATCH AGAINST. I've used before in another project without any issue and utilising the same base code, except I'm having some odd behaviour. The only real difference is that I am using MariaDB instead of MySQL.

Below is how my table is defined

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LogID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LogReceived` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Host` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LogName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `LogLine` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDXLogID` (`LogID`,`LogReceived`,`Host`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `IDXLogLine` (`LogLine`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5838772 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

One of the columns that I am doing the full text search against contains the following:

`19/06/2019 19:01:18:   Took 0 seconds to read lines for log 'Log Agent'`

If I do the query as follows (LogLine is the column with the full text search):

`SELECT * FROM log_agent.temp_logs WHERE MATCH(LogLine) AGAINST ('+Log' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

But the above query returns no results, even though as shown above the column value contains `Log`. If I try changing `+Log` to be `+seconds` it then returns the row so why does it find `seconds` but not `Log`, again if I change `+Log` for `+Agent` rows are returned so their doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason for what its doing.

I've tried removing the `IN BOOLEAN MODE` as I didn't need this previously but makes no difference.

Comment: More than 50% of the lines contain "Log"?

Comment: pretty much every line does but why should that matter. From when I've used it in the past it didn't matter if only 1 row had the keyword or 6000 rows had the keyword.

Comment: @RickJames Over 90% contain log but also Agent is over 90% of the rows but that gets returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 caveats in using MyISAM's `FULLTEXT`:

- Words that occur in more than half the rows are not indexed.
- Words shorter than `ft_min_word_len` are not indexed.
- Words in the "stop word" list are not indexed.

When filtering on things that `FULLTEXT` prefers to ignore, this trick is useful:

```
WHERE MATCH(`LogLine`) AGAINST ('...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  -- things that FT can do
  AND `LogLine` LIKE "..."  -- (or NOT LIKE or RLIKE or NOT RLIKE, as needed)
```

This will be reasonably efficient because it will first do the FT test, which will find only a few rows.  Then it will go to the extra effort on those rows.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the reason. Looking the data, the keywords `Logs` is 96% of the rows, `Seconds` is 31% of the rows and Agent is 90% of the rows. Seconds and Agent are returned which based on your first point only Seconds should be as its less than half the rows. None of the keywords I am using are in the stop word list and for the second point, should that be longer than `ft_max_word_len` are not indexed as my value is 84 and all the keywords I've used are less than but some are returned

Comment: @Boardy - typo --> ft_min_word_len.  It defaults to 4; "Log" is only 3.

Comment: Assuming 4, I expect "Log" to be ignored for 2 reasons, and "Agent" to be ignored for one.  So, it will find 31% of the rows, those that include "Seconds".  I cannot explain why "+Log +Agent" is returning anything.

Comment: Ah that explains why log isn't found. Is there another way to do what I am after I thought about doing `col LIKE '%Log% AND col LIKE '%Agent%` but that seems a little inefficient

Comment: @Boardy - See my addition.

Comment: Number 3 can be changed using `ft_stopword_file` or `innodb_ft_enable_stopword`.
What about number 1? I can't find where that is.

Comment: @Syco - I don't think the 50% cutoff can be changed.